# Transaction doesn't work when instantiating eloquant from a class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to use transactions OUTSIDE laravel. it works when I include the db instantiation right in my index file as is:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Db;



$db = new Db;

$db->addConnection( [
    'driver'    => Settings::DATABASE_DRIVER,
    'host'      => Settings::DATABASE_HOST,
    'database'  => Settings::DATABASE_NAME,
    'username'  => Settings::DATABASE_USERNAME,
    'password'  => Settings::DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
] );

# Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$db->setAsGlobal();
```

I can then elsewhere use code like this:

```
Db::connection()->beginTransaction();

# Create blog post in the database and return its id
$blogPostRecordId = ( new BlogDbModel() )->create( $_POST );
Db::connection()-> rollBack();
```

it will correctly work and rollback: no row is created in db.

However, If I get an instance of the db from a class, it won't work:

```
class DbSql
{

    /**
     * Use the eloquent query builder and orm. Bypass PDO interface.
     * @return Capsule
     */
    public function db()
    {
        $capsule = new Capsule;

        $capsule->addConnection( [
            'driver'    => Settings::DATABASE_DRIVER,
            'host'      => Settings::DATABASE_HOST,
            'database'  => Settings::DATABASE_NAME,
            'username'  => Settings::DATABASE_USERNAME,
            'password'  => Settings::DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => ''
        ] );

        # Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
        $capsule->setAsGlobal();

        // Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
        //$capsule->bootEloquent();


        return $capsule;
    }
}
```

and then use

```
( new DbSql() )->db()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

# Create blog post in the database and return its id
$blogPostRecordId = ( new BlogDbModel() )->create( $_POST );
( new DbSql() )->db()->getConnection()->rollBack();
```

it simply won't work and the transaction is ignored. Why does getting the db instance from a class instantiation make the process fail ? I would prefer to use an instance as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: the db instance must be exactly the same everywhere the transaction is needed:

```
$dbInstance = ( new DbSql() )->db();
```

Then use $dbInstance wherever the transaction is to be followed:

```
$dbInstance->connection()->beginTransaction();
```

as well as with any db eloquent operation. So pass the $dbInstance as needed. The good thing is that it can be anywhere in you code: in your models, controllers....

Then finish:

```
 $dbInstance->connection()->commit();
```

If the system is not able to reach this last line, nothing will be committed to the db.